# Numpy broadcasting elementwise product on all pairs of rows?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1d ndarray `A` of shape (n,) and a 2d ndarray `E` of shape (n,m). I am trying to preform the following calculation (the circle-dot denotes element wise multiplication):

[image]

I have written it using with a for loop, but this block of code is called thousands of times, and I was hoping there was a way to accomplish this with broadcasting or numpy functions. The following is my for loop solution I'm trying to rewrite:

```
def fun(E, A):
    X = E * A[:,np.newaxis]
    R = np.zeros(E.shape[-1])
    for ii in xrange(len(E)-1):
        for jj in xrange(ii+1, len(E)):
            R += X[ii] * X[jj]
    return R
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Current approach, but still not working:

```
def fun1(E, A):
    X = E * A[:,np.newaxis]
    R = np.zeros(E.shape[-1])
    for ii in xrange(len(E)-1):
        for jj in xrange(ii+1, len(E)):
            R += X[ii] * X[jj]
    return R

def fun2(E, A):
    n = E.shape[0]
    m = E.shape[1]

    A_ = np.triu(A[1:] * A[:-1].reshape(-1,1))
    E_ = E[1:] * E[:-1] 
    R = np.sum((A_.reshape(n-1, 1, n-1) * E_.T).transpose(0,2,1).reshape(n-1*n-1,m), axis=0)

    return R

A = np.arange(4,9)
E = np.arange(20).reshape((5,4))

print fun1(E,A)
print fun2(E,A)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, this should work:

```
def fun3(E,A):
    n,m = E.shape
    n_ = n - 1

    X = E * A[:, np.newaxis]
    a = (X[:-1].reshape(n_, 1, m) * X[1:])
    b = np.tril(np.ones((m, n_, n_))).T
    R = np.sum((a*b).reshape(n_*n_, m), axis=0)

    return R
```

Last function was only based on the given formula. This is instead based on `fun` and tested with your added test case.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @rikardolsson, but this does not seem to be working for me.  I wrote a little test case, but I'm not sure the best way to share it here, so I edited my original post and put it at the bottom.

Comment: Maybe I should’ve replied with a new answer instead of editing this one. But hopefully you did see that it was edited.

Comment: It works now.  The first line of my function (i.e., `X = E * A[:,np.newaxis]`) was to eliminate redundant scalar multiplications from `A`.